# How to align an image on css?

Tags: html, css

I want to put an image on the left side of my Home page. I know how to do it in html but I want to create it in a CSS class. I don't know what I need to do to fix it. The picture I want is called Nobullying.jpg
HTML:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="body.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Bully-Free Zone</h1>
  <h2>"Online harassment has an off-line impact"</h2>
  <!--Menu-->I
  <div id="nav">
  <a href="mainpage.htm" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
  <a href="page1.htm" class="nav-link">ASSISTANCE</a>
  <a href="page2.htm" class="nav-link">CYBER-BULLYING SIGNS</a> 
  <a href="page3.htm" class="nav-link">REPORT</a>
  </div>
  <div id="picture"></div>
  <!--Copyright-->
  <div id="center">
  <td> Copyright © 2012 Bully-FreeZone.com</td>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Css class:

```
   #picture{background-image:Nobullying.jpg;
   width:40px; height:40px;
   }
```

This is where I want the picture. (Red box)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMyVo.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#picture { 
 background-image:url('no-bullying.jpg');
 height:100px;
 width:50px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom:10px;
 left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile what would I have in my HTML

Comment: Why are you using both the `<img>` tag and the css `background-image`? Not only is that redundant, but it can cause bugs if the images don't align due to padding or positioning. Also, @Backtrack said they wanted to do the image in CSS, not through html.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust your CSS like so:

```
#picture{
   background-image:url('/path/to/Nobullying.jpg');
   width:40px; height:40px;
   position: absolute; /* this removes it from document flow */
   left: 5px; /* this places image 5px away from the leftmost area of the container */
              /* you can choose from left/right and top/bottom for positioning */
              /* play around with those and you should get a hang of how it works */
}
```

Remember: when you use css background images, the path is from the perspective of the css file (not the html file the css is included in).

So if your directory structure was like

```
root
--> css    -> styles.css
--> images -> Nobullying.jpg
--> index.html
```

Then your path could be `url('../images/Nobullying.jpg')` or `url('/images/Nobullying.jpg');

Comment: Can you I use both bottom and top because It's not working when I use both. It just does top

Comment: @Backtrack no, you cannot combine bottom and top; you also cannot combine left and right. But you can do left+bottom or right+top. Here is a good article to understand the principles behind CSS positioning: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `fixed` positioning to keep it in that position regardless of scrolling.

```
#picture{
    background: url(Nobullying.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;

    position: fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    left:10px;
```

}

*also use url() and no-repeat for the background-image.*

Comment: `no-repeat` needs to be used separately with the `background-repeat` rule unless using `background` [shorthand](http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/).

Comment: Updated answer. Add a comment next time you down vote otherwise its useless.

Comment: Sorry for the apparently hostility, you commented before I finished my comment

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your `background-image` rule. Besides that, you can use `position:absolute` to position the element

```
#picture{
    background-image: url(Nobullying.jpg);
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#picture{
   background-image:url(Nobullying.jpg);
   width:40px; height:40px;
   float:left;
   }
```

I have used ID here not a class. The image should be identified with the ID="picture".

In CSS it gets a little tricky when you use float. If you can already do this in html, just use html. Otherwise, you will have to learn a few extra things.

*The answer is updated*